# Inflection usage for fetching model in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am confused at how EmberJS uses inflection to fetch data from local database.

Given that I have a model called `Post`, I have seen instances of:

```
this.store.find('post', 1); //This one makese sense to me. Find a record of post with ID 1
```

I am more confused at when the tutorial starts adding/omitting 's'.

What are the differences between:

`this.store.find('post');`

`this.store.find('posts');`

`this.store.all('post');` //This one also makes sense. Find all records of post.

The one that specifically confuses me is `this.store.find('posts');` when I only have `Post` model, because it will actually throw an error telling me that `No model was found: posts`. Nonetheless, I still see it in the tutorial and getting started. Is this just a typo in the tutorial? This is the toturial that I am referring to:

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

and go to Dynamic Routes section.

Comment: Why are you mixing a question about models names with an example of resources names?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate? The guide uses two ways of fetching its model `this.find('post');` and `this.find('posts');`. I would like to know the difference. IF the guide had 2 different models (post and posts, with the extra s), then that would make sense, but the guide has no mention of two such models. Thus, I am assuming that both calls are acting on a single model, that is post.

Comment: I misread a line, but I think you already have your answer: `it will actually throw an error telling me that No model was found: posts` :) prepare evidence, a small test case, and send them a PR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my previous comments into an answer in case someone else stumbles upon this before a fix is live.

I feel this has been wrongly downvoted. It is actually a mistake with the guides, as the singular form should be used throughout. The OP's confusion was entirely warranted.

The [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/website/pull/1846) submitted to correct this issue has already been merged.